# $A \rightarrow B$ injective implies $f^{\#}$ an injective morphism of sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
Had something I was thinking about and wanted to check if I was mistaken anywhere.  Let $Y = \Spec A, X = \Spec B$ be affine schemes, with $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ a ring homomorphism with corresponding morphism $(f,f^{\#}): X \rightarrow Y$.

Suppose that $\phi$ is injective.  Then for every prime $\mathfrak p$ of $A$, we get an injective ring homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p} = A_{\mathfrak p} \otimes_A A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak p} \otimes_A B = S^{-1}B$, where $S = A - \mathfrak p$.

Then $f^{\#}: \mathcal O_Y \rightarrow f_{\ast}\mathcal O_X$ is an injective morphism of sheaves, since if we check at each stalk, we have

$$(f_{\ast} \mathcal O_X)_\mathfrak p = \varinjlim_{V \ni \mathfrak p} \mathcal O_X(f^{-1}\mathfrak p) = \varinjlim_{x \in A - \mathfrak p} \mathcal O_X(D_B(x)) = \varinjlim_{x \in S} B_x = S^{-1}B$$

and $f^{\#}_{\mathfrak p}$ is just this ring homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow S^{-1}B$, which is injective.

So the injectivity of $\phi$ is equivalent to the injectivity of the morphism of sheaves $f^{\#}$?

Comment: Yes ; see Exercise II.2.18 b) in Hartshorne.

Comment: Oh..I did that exercise before and didn't remember it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is correct, in fact the argument can be made a little easier.

> **Basic commutative algebra**: if $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules and $f:M\to N$ is an $A$-module homomorphism, then $f$ is injective if and only if $f_{\mathfrak p}:M_{\mathfrak p}\to N_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective for all primes $\mathfrak p\subset A$.

Going to our case, the ring morphism $f:A\to B$ is also a homomorphism of $A$-modules when we consider $B$ as an $A$-module via $f$. Since the "localization" at $\mathfrak p\subseteq A$, i.e. $A_{\mathfrak p}\to B_{\mathfrak p}$, is the same as the stalk at $\mathfrak p$ of the sheaf morphsim $\mathcal O_Y\to f_*\mathcal O_X$, and a morphism of sheaves is injective if and only if its injective at all stalks, the result follows immediately from our above cited fact.

As an aside, this is the geometric reason that a property like the one highlighted is typically called a "local property".